# Gazebo seems to be crashing

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is after much fooling around, so I feel like some state, cache, or something else is corrupted. I have rebooted the operating system and that didn't seem to do it. Do you maybe see what's wrong? Thanks!

```
roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo turtlebot_world.launch 
... logging to /home/pitosalas/.ros/log/b8039b42-7fad-11e7-8e19-000c29404713/roslaunch-ubuntu-9680.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

xacro: Traditional processing is deprecated. Switch to --inorder processing!
To check for compatibility of your document, use option --check-order.
For more infos, see http://wiki.ros.org/xacro#Processing_Order
xacro.py is deprecated; please use xacro instead
started roslaunch server http://localhost:42313/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /bumper2pointcloud/pointcloud_radius: 0.24
 * /cmd_vel_mux/yaml_cfg_file: /opt/ros/kinetic/...
 * /depthimage_to_laserscan/output_frame_id: /camera_depth_frame
 * /depthimage_to_laserscan/range_min: 0.45
 * /depthimage_to_laserscan/scan_height: 10
 * /robot_description: <?xml version="1....
 * /robot_state_publisher/publish_frequency: 30.0
 * /rosdistro: kinetic
 * /rosversion: 1.12.7
 * /use_sim_time: True

NODES
  /
    bumper2pointcloud (nodelet/nodelet)
    cmd_vel_mux (nodelet/nodelet)
    depthimage_to_laserscan (nodelet/nodelet)
    gazebo (gazebo_ros/gzserver)
    gazebo_gui (gazebo_ros/gzclient)
    laserscan_nodelet_manager (nodelet/nodelet)
    mobile_base_nodelet_manager (nodelet/nodelet)
    robot_state_publisher (robot_state_publisher/robot_state_publisher)
    spawn_turtlebot_model (gazebo_ros/spawn_model)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

core service [/rosout] found
process[gazebo-1]: started with pid [9701]
process[gazebo_gui-2]: started with pid [9706]
process[spawn_turtlebot_model-3]: started with pid [9711]
process[mobile_base_nodelet_manager-4]: started with pid [9712]
process[cmd_vel_mux-5]: started with pid [9713]
process[bumper2pointcloud-6]: started with pid [9714]
process[robot_state_publisher-7]: started with pid [9715]
process[laserscan_nodelet_manager-8]: started with pid [9722]
process[depthimage_to_laserscan-9]: started with pid [9733]
[gazebo-1] process has died [pid 9701, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/gazebo_ros/gzserver -e ode /opt/ros/kinetic/share/turtlebot_gazebo/worlds/playground.world __name:=gazebo __log:=/home/pitosalas/.ros/log/b8039b42-7fad-11e7-8e19-000c29404713/gazebo-1.log].
log file: /home/pitosalas/.ros/log/b8039b42-7fad-11e7-8e19-000c29404713/gazebo-1*.log
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::system::system_error'
  what():  End of file
Aborted (core dumped)
[gazebo_gui-2] process has died [pid 9706, exit code 134, cmd /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/gazebo_ros/gzclient __name:=gazebo_gui __log:=/home/pitosalas/.ros/log/b8039b42-7fad-11e7-8e19-000c29404713/gazebo_gui-2.log].
log file: /home/pitosalas/.ros/log/b8039b42-7fad-11e7-8e19-000c29404713/gazebo_gui-2*.log
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/268669/gazebo-seems-to-be-crashing/) by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 628 on 2017-08-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not very helpful response: it has stopped crashing. Of all the things I tried, including rebooting the computer and killing all terminal windows, perhaps killing all processes that had /ros/ in their name did the trick. I am not sure but I think that was it.

---

Originally posted by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) with karma: 628 on 2017-08-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-08-13**:
This happens once in a while. I use `htop` to find and kill processes that won't die.